# Elasticsearch unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, kibana, lets-encrypt

I am trying to encrypt tls certificate using LetsEncrypt. But my server page says: `Kibana server is not ready yet`.

Here is the error in `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-29T09:48:26+00:00","tags":["error","elasticsearch-service"],"pid":476059,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. unable to get issuer certificate"}
```

I was using the same config with a self signed CA before, but it was working. But when I switched to LetsEncrypt, it does not work. The `.pem` files are same for both Kibana and Elasticsearch, and are copied from `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/my.exampledomain.com/`.

**Elasticsearch Configuration:**

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#network.host: localhost
#network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: [ _eth0_, _local_ ]

http.port: 9200

#discovery.seed_hosts: my.exampledomain.com
discovery.type: single-node
xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled: true

xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/privkey2.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/cert2.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/fullchain2.pem" ]

xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/privkey2.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/cert2.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "/etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/fullchain2.pem" ]
```

**Kibana Configuration:**

```
server.port: 5601

#server.host: "localhost"
#server.host: "my.exampledomain.com"
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

server.publicBaseUrl: "https://my.exampledomain.com"

#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://0.0.0.0:9200"]
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://my.exampledomain.com:9200"]

elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ["/etc/kibana/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/fullchain2.pem"]
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: "certificate"
#elasticsearch.ssl.verify: true


xpack.security.sameSiteCookies: "None"
xpack.security.secureCookies: true

xpack.security.authc.providers:
  basic.basic1:
    order: 0

# Enable Kibana TLS over HTTPS

server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/fullchain2.pem
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/ssl/my.exampledomain.com/privkey2.pem
```

**Elasticsearch Test:**
[Elasticsearch server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6GLv.png)

Comment: Having the same issue. Using curl with the cert auth file I can connect to Elastic. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Also having the same issue, tried changing the certificateAuthorities key in both elasticsearch and kibana configs to be any and all of the letsencrypt certs that they give you (chain, cert, privkey, fullchain) but it doesn't seem to have any effect. @BJury wondering if you can share your exact final configuration

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and after days of searching I finally figured out that although Elasticsearch accepts chain.pem as a certificate authority cert when using privkey.pem and fullchain.pem as your key and cert, respectively, Kibana does not.

For some reason Kibana needs the public root CA cert from letsencrypt, isrgrootx1.pem, which can be downloaded from letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem

Once you have this cert downloaded your cert configuration can be as follows:

```bash
# ES cert setup:
xpack.security.http.ssl.key=privkey.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=fullchain.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=chain.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=privkey.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=fullchain.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=chain.pem

# Kibana cert setup:
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities=isrgrootx1.pem
server.ssl.key=privkey.pem
server.ssl.certificate=fullchain.pem
server.ssl.certificateAuthorities=chain.pem
```

And everything should work!

Comment: This was it! Nowhere in the Let's Encrypt method for setting up Kibana does it mention the need for Let's encrypt's public root CA. Great find!

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue. It was resolved by including the cert for each step in the chain, including the root certificate in both `certificateAuthorities` properties.

Something that Elastic didn't seem to need.

This is on Kibana 8.2.0.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you did that? Do you mean that you had to put extra entries in kibana.yml/elasticsearch.yml under the elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities key besides just the fullchain2.pem file? Or that you still only have 1 entry but you appended certs to the file? I am having this exact same issue but cant seem to fix it

Comment: @Nick We had a root CA, and a intermediary CA, so had to put both in. eg `server.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/usr/share/kibana/config/ca-inter.crt", "/usr/share/kibana/config/ca-root.crt" ]`

Comment: and `elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/usr/share/kibana/config/ca-inter.crt", "/usr/share/kibana/config/ca-root.crt" ]`

Comment: Are those certificates self signed or given to you by letsencrypt? Or are they available on the internet somewhere like the `isrgrootx1.pem` root ca that letsencrypt uses is?

Comment: @Nick they're just the public certs of whoever signed what you have. You can generally export them using your browser while viewing the certificate.

Comment: I created a root.pem and intermediary.pem by taking the last and second to last certificate block out of my fullchain.pem file that LE gives you, but still to no avail. I wonder what the exact config of elasticsearch needs to be in order for that to work. Should I use privkey.pem as the key, fullchain.pem as the cert, and chain.pem as the CA as suggested by elasticsearch themselves?

Comment: turns out the public CA cert isrgrootx1.pem from letsencrypt does the trick!