# Elasticsearch and Kibana not working with Letsencrypt certs

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

Kibana can't connect to Elasticsearch using Letsencrypt signed certs

I am trying to run a 3 node elasticsearch cluster with kibana using letsencrypt certs. I have copy pasted the standard docker-compose.yml and environment file from the official elasticsearch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html), and successfully got it working with self signed certs without error. When i try and swap out the self signed certs for lets encrypt signed certs the elasticsearch cluster works but kibana stops working with the error

```
kibana_1  | [2022-09-12T18:52:55.669+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. unable to get issuer certificate
```

The letsencrypt signed certs are all properly mounted into the container with the same owner/group and permissions as the self signed certs, for example

```
-rw-r----- 1 root     root   991 Sep 12 14:03 bundle.zip
drwxr-x--- 2 root     root  4096 Sep 12 13:38 ca
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  2512 Sep 12 13:38 ca.zip
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  1899 Sep 12 14:03 cert.pem
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  7610 Sep 12 13:38 certs.zip
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  3749 Sep 12 14:03 chain.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 root     root  4096 Sep 12 13:38 es01
drwxr-x--- 2 root     root  4096 Sep 12 13:38 es02
drwxr-x--- 2 root     root  4096 Sep 12 13:38 es03
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  5648 Sep 12 14:03 fullchain.pem
-rw-r----- 1 root     root   272 Sep 12 13:38 instances.yml
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  1826 Sep 12 14:03 intermediary.pem
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  1704 Sep 12 14:03 privkey.pem
-rw-r----- 1 root     root  1923 Sep 12 14:03 root.pem
```

Which i achieved by running these commands as suggested in the official docs

```
sudo find certs/ -type f -exec chmod 640 "{}" \;
sudo find certs -type d -exec chmod 750 "{}" \;
```

The intermediary.pem and root.pem certs were split out from the fullchain.pem cert and tried as part of the CA cert bundle as suggested in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430152/elasticsearch-unable-to-get-issuer-certificate#:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A). I have tried many different combinations of these certs in both the elastic search and kibana config and although more than one way works for the elastic search nodes, none of them work with kibana.

This is the final attempt i made, using `privkey.pem` as the key, `fullchain.pem` as the cert, and `chain.pem` as the CA, as suggested [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/x-pack-security-for-elasticsearch-with-lets-encrypt-certificates) in the elasticsearch docs. The below file omits the "setup" container that you will see in the official docs.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es02:
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es03:
    depends_on:
      - es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
      es03:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - SERVERNAME=dev.mysite.com
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://dev.mysite.com:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/chain.pem
 ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://dev.mysite.com:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  esdata03:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

### .env

```
# Password for the 'elastic' user (at least 6 characters)
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=asdf1234

# Password for the 'kibana_system' user (at least 6 characters)
KIBANA_PASSWORD=asdf1234

# Version of Elastic products
STACK_VERSION=8.4.1

# Set the cluster name
CLUSTER_NAME=docker-cluster

# Set to 'basic' or 'trial' to automatically start the 30-day trial
LICENSE=basic
#LICENSE=trial

# Port to expose Elasticsearch HTTP API to the host
ES_PORT=9200
#ES_PORT=127.0.0.1:9200

# Port to expose Kibana to the host
KIBANA_PORT=5601
#KIBANA_PORT=80

# Increase or decrease based on the available host memory (in bytes)
MEM_LIMIT=1073741824

# Project namespace (defaults to the current folder name if not set)
#COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject
```

I have verified that elasticsearch is working both by the lack of errors in the output of the containers and also by running

```
curl -u elastic:asdf1234 https://dev.mysite.com:9200/_cluster/health
```

which gives me the output

```
{"cluster_name":"docker-cluster","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":3,"number_of_data_nodes":3,"active_primary_shards":11,"active_shards":22,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

Comment: The certificate should just be the certificate related to the key (not a chain) and the CA is typically the needed root certificates for the remote party certificates, to validate them.

Comment: So of the 4 certs that letsencrypt gives you (cert.pem, chain.pem, privkey.pem, fullchain.pem) which would i use for the CA?

Comment: None. What you need to use as CA depends on the remote side you connect to and how you will validate the certificates you receive from the other side. It is unrelated to your side (the other side should obviously have the CA related to your certificates, otherwise they won't validate yours if you are in a mutual TLS authentication mode). Note that the names of files and extensions do not matter so much. Only the content is important.

Comment: The 2 sides here are the elasticsearch nodes and the kibana instance. If the elasticsearch nodes are using the typical letsencrypt certs for encryption and the "chain.pem" file works for each of the nodes as the CA when they communicate with each other why wouldn't it work for kibana? Do I need to use some other LE CA thats related to my certificates like isrgrootx1.pem? Sorry im new to certs but just confused about how it could work for inter-node comms and also the command line but not for kibana. im just looking for a specific CA cert i should use based on the typical LE certs

Comment: Okay just tried the letsencrypt CA cert isrgrootx1.pem which can be found at letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem and it worked! I wish this would be clearly stated somewhere as certs can be very confusing especially to new people. Not sure why Kibana needs this but ES does not. Your comment pushed me in the right direction thanks @PatrickMevzek

Comment: The PKI works this way: each party (think each side of a TLS communication) has a list of "trusted" root certificates, often called a truststore. when it connects to another party, this other party sends its certificate, and now locally you test if that certificate was issued by one of the CA you trust (which are the trusted root you maintain locally). If so you go forward with TLS, if not you stop. This is not the only way to do it (you could instead explicitly vet given certificates for example, see DNS DANE standard), but the most often used one. Hence "CA" always refer to **remote** side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Elasticsearch for some reason in Kibana you cannot use any of the certs that letsencrypt gives you as the CA. You must find the public root CA cert of letsencrypt itself, which is isrgrootx1.pem and can be downloaded from letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem. Unfortunately none of this is clear in any documentation anywhere and after days of fruitless searching I stumbled upon this in another SO question!

Once you have that cert you can bind it into the container and then update the config to look like this

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es02:
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es03:
    depends_on:
      - es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/chain.pem https://dev.mysite.com:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
      es03:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
      - ./certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - SERVERNAME=dev.mysite.com
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://dev.mysite.com:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/isrgrootx1.pem
      - SERVER_SSL_ENABLED="true"
      - SERVER_SSL_KEY=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/privkey.pem
      - SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/fullchain.pem
      - SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/chain.pem
 ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://dev.mysite.com:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  esdata03:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

Now everything should work fine!